# Empty recordset when requesting records from two schedules

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

This is an SQL query problem more than anything.  I am testing the following:

```
SELECT Employees.Corps_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name, Shifts.Start_Date_Time, Shifts.End_Date_Time, DateDiff('n',Shifts.Start_Date_Time,Shifts.End_Date_Time) AS SubTotalMinutes, Locations.Location_Name
FROM (Locations INNER JOIN Shifts ON Locations.Location_ID = Shifts.Location) INNER JOIN (Employees INNER JOIN Employees_Shifts ON Employees.Employee_ID = Employees_Shifts.Employee_ID) ON Shifts.Shift_ID = Employees_Shifts.Shift_ID
WHERE (((Shifts.Start_Date_Time) Between #2015/09/26# And #2015/10/04#) AND ((Shifts.Schedule_ID)=1 And (Shifts.Schedule_ID)=2))
ORDER BY Employees.Last_Name;
```

This query is part of a scheduling application in Access 2010, and the query attempts to obtain records that span the last week in September thru to the first week in October.  This would be regarded as a pay period.  Each Schedule covers one month.  So, in order to get all the records for the first part of October, I need to include the line: ***And (Shifts.Schedule_ID)=2)***

If I remove that line the query runs fine and I get, at least the records from the last week in September.  But including the line gives me an empty recordset.  I don't know why that is. There are records for both schedules.  Schedule 1 covers all of September, Schedule 2 covers all of October. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the logical OR :)

((Shifts.Schedule_ID)=1 or (Shifts.Schedule_ID)=2))

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.